# R plot over a background image with coordinates

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a factory layout in png format shown below.
And I have item moving activity data with coordinates ( starts from (0,0) and ends at (100,100)) like:

```
x y
0 4
2 5
4 100
```

(0,4) means item showing in this position and I want to plot a dot. (0,100) indicates the lower-right endpoint.

I expected certain area has darker color if it visited more frequently.

How to plot the activity data into picture file with the right scale respected to the size of the pic?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(png)
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)

d <- data.frame(x=c(0,2,4), y= c(4,5,100))

r <- png::readPNG('factory.png')
rg <- grid::rasterGrob(r, width=unit(1,"npc"), height=unit(1,"npc"))

ggplot(d, aes(x,y)) + 
  annotation_custom(rg) +
  geom_point(colour="red") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0), lim=c(0,100)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0), lim=c(0,100)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(aspect.ratio = nrow(r)/ncol(r))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you load the image into R as a raster image, you can plot it with the `rasterImage` function.

```
## Your data
PTS = read.table(text="x y
0 4
2 5
4 100", 
header=TRUE)

library(png)
IM = readPNG(file.choose())
plot(NULL, xlim=c(0,100), ylim=c(0,100), axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="")
rasterImage(IM,0,0,100,100)
points(PTS[,2:1], pch=20, col="red")
```

[image: PNG IMage]

Notice that I used the y coordinates first, then the x's for the `points` function to match your statement "(0,100) indicates the lower-right endpoint."

If you want to show high traffic by darker color,  use a transparent color so that the depth of the color adds up. Your three points aren't enough to show that so I made up some other bogus data to illustrate this.

```
x = c(rnorm(400,40,10), rnorm(100,40,5))
y = 43 + rnorm(500,0,1)
plot(NULL, xlim=c(0,100), ylim=c(0,100), axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="")
rasterImage(IM,0,0,100,100)
points(y,x, pch=20, col="#33333322")
```

[image: Point Density]

Comment: thank you for your answer! How do change the origin start from  the upper left?

Comment: you can plot  (100 - x) against y